# Visual Studio 2019 (itself): Exception Has Been Thrown By The Target of an Invocation

Tags: visual-studio, exception, invoke

Last night I installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, installed most of my usual extensions and played around bit, without issue. Shut it down, then this morning when I fired it back up, just after the VS splash screen I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

After that, VS just exits. I've tried running VS in `/safemode` but the same thing happens. After running [ProcDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) (`Procdump64.exe -w devenv.exe -e 1 -n 1000 -f *TargetInvocationException* -ma > out.txt`) no .dmp files are created, but the out.txt file shows this:

```
Waiting for process named devenv.exe...

Process:               devenv.exe (10576)
Process image:         C:\Coding\IDE\VS2019\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
CPU threshold:         n/a
Performance counter:   n/a
Commit threshold:      n/a
Threshold seconds:     n/a
Hung window check:     Disabled
Log debug strings:     Disabled
Exception monitor:     First Chance+Unhandled
Exception filter:      [Includes]
                       *TargetInvocationException*
                       [Excludes]
Terminate monitor:     Disabled
Cloning type:          Disabled
Concurrent limit:      n/a
Avoid outage:          n/a
Number of dumps:       1000
Dump folder:           C:\Downloads\
Dump filename/mask:    PROCESSNAME_YYMMDD_HHMMSS
Queue to WER:          Disabled
Kill after dump:       Disabled


Press Ctrl-C to end monitoring without terminating the process.

[16:33:52] Exception: 04242420
[16:33:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E06D7363.msc
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:56] Exception: E0434352.CLR
[16:33:57] The process has exited.
[16:33:57] Dump count not reached.
```

I've also tried running `sfc /scannow`, `devenv /updateconfiguration`, checking for any new Windows updates, and running VS as Admin, but still stuck at this spot. Until I get this fixed Visual Studio 2019 is useless to me. Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

​Well, while I still have no idea what exactly got screwed up, after waiting a while, I decided to try a re-install over the top of the previous installation in hopes of it fixing itself; running the installer showed there's an update to VS 2019 as well as an update to VS 2017, so I updated both and when it was all done vs 2019 was able to start again.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurred for me after i limited windows UAC settings, and solved by running the VS as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Open Windows Explorer, and navigate to `<Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE` (by default is `C:\Program Files or Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`);
2. Delete the `ItemTemplatesCache`, `ProjectTemplatesCache` folders;
3. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt under `Start menu -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools` (run it with administrative privilege);
4. Run the `devenv /InstallVSTemplates` switch;
5. Run the `devenv /Setup` switch

Answer (score 0):

Just Repair your visual studio 2017

[image]